# Eclipse IDE on Mac OS X doesn't find correct JDK path after update JDK

Tags: java, ios, eclipse, macos

I've been using Eclipse/Java on Mac OS for a long time. Recently, I tried to launch Eclipse, and it opened its splash page and quit. I downloaded Neon, and it won't let me install Eclipse because it finds an old version of Java on my system, though my system tell me I've got Java 8. I've got El Capitan running

Any advice?

Comment: Any error messages from starting Eclipse? Try starting it from a shell or check its log file. What is $JAVA_HOME set to?

Comment: Make sure it is the JDK you have installed, the JRE is not enough.

Answer (score 0):

You set JDK path like this screenshot:

[image]

(Image source: http://crunchify.com/where-is-java-installed-on-my-mac-osx-system/)